# Coroutine Scope correct implementation with states

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-jetpack-compose

I am making a retail app using MVVM Architecture and Jetpack Compose.

Scenario.

1. Create page for creating a store visit, there is a Save button on topbar.
2. On click of save, have to show a dropdown menu with two items, Save and Save and Open, first option is to save the visit, second is to save and open the same visit detail page but with a visibility of navigation.

Issue: I am using Coroutine scope to save and navigate to other screen. I am showing 3ms delay, what if the response doesnt comes at 3 ms.how to show a message if the api fails. how this can be done in concrete way:
Please suggest, as I need to show the navigation from save visit to the next save detail page.

```
 DropdownMenu(
            expanded = viewModel.isDropdownMenuExpanded,
            onDismissRequest = { viewModel.isDropdownMenuExpanded = false }
        ) {
           
            for (title in SaveVisitActions.values())
                DropdownMenuItem(
                    onClick = {
                        when (title) {
                            SaveVisitActions.SAVE -> {
                                viewModel.handleSave()
                            }
                            SaveVisitActions.SAVEANDOPEN -> {
                                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                                    delay(3000)
                                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                                        if (viewModel.isCreateSuccess.value) {
                                            navController.navigate(
                                                "${Screen.VisitDetailScreen.route}/${viewModel.objectState.value?.id}"
                                            )
                                        }

                                    }
                                }
                                viewModel.handleSave()

                            }
                        }
                    }) {
                    Text(text = title.title)
                }
        }
```

Below is the launched effect

```
LaunchedEffect(viewModel.isCreateSuccess) {
    snapshotFlow { viewModel.isCreateSuccess.value }
        .filter { it }
        .collect {
            for (title in SaveVisitActions.values()) {
                if (title == SaveVisitActions.SAVEANDOPEN) {
                    navController.navigate(
                        "${Screen.VisitDetailScreen.route}/${viewModel.objectState.value?.id}"
                    )

                }
                if (navController.currentDestination?.route?.compareTo(Screen.VisitCreateScreen.route) == 0) {
                    navController.setDataToPreviousBackStackAndPop(
                        key = Constants.APPOINTMENT_SUCCESS_RESULT_KEY,
                        value = Constants.APPOINTMENT_SUCCESS_RESULT_KEY
                    )
                }
            }

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use join() function that is a suspending function, i.e it can be called from a coroutine or from within another suspending function. Job blocks all the threads until the coroutine in which it is written or have context finished its work. Only when the coroutine gets finishes, lines after the join() function will be executed.

Comment: how about LaunchedEffect()

Answer (score 0):

use await() method to wait for the value you are waiting for. I suppose you are waiting for the value of isCreateSuccess in your view model. create a job that waits for a value returned by a suspend function waiting for your success value from the view model.

```
val handleSave = async { waitForSuccess() }

if(handleSave.await()){
    viewModel.handleSave()
}else{
     // show your error here
}

suspend fun waitForSuccess() : Boolean{
    // get your Success Value from view model here
}
```

Comment: What if waitForSuccess() returns false, I need to show message. How to do that

Comment: just execute the error message in else block

Comment: how about LaunchedEffect()

Comment: you want to execute this piece of code inside your onClick. Launched Effect is for when you are executing code that is unrelated to composable outside a function like onClick. Like, when you want to observe a value in the ViewModel, you can use launched effect but for your use case, there is no need for it.

Comment: I am actually observing isCreateSuccess from ViewModel and if its value is true, I have to save the form and navigate to its detail screen else if api fails it should not navigate to the detail screen

Comment: you are not observing isCreateSuccess, you are just accessing its value. you will be observing if you are using livedata and observing the value or using a stateflow and collecting it inside your composable. Now, what you can do here is create a launched effect in composable above your for loop. Give your isCreateSuccess as the key so whenever there will be a change in its value launched effect will fire off and you can execute accordingly whatever you want to do when isCreateSuccess returns the correct value.

Comment: Thanks fro the reply, I have already tried doing it but the thing is I have 4 options in dropdown , each will have a separate  launched effect which overrides the other. Now each option triggers the same effect and navigation.Updated code in the question which I have tried.

Comment: just create different functions for different options. create a handleSaveAndOpen() and maybe create another value isCreateSuccessAndOpen and create another launched effect that listens for different values. This way you won't need to worry about option triggering same effect.

Comment: Thanks, I have done the same, am still facing the issue. So at every click I want to do handleSave and then navigate which I have handled in Launched Effect but even though creating different functions and mutable states, it still overides the previous effect. 
May be I guess its because am calling the same method in different func
 fun handleSaveAndOpen() {
    handleSave()
}

fun handleSaveAndNew() {
    handleSave()
}

Comment: or else I think the dropdown option state is not captured properly, Any idea how to check whether what is clicked from dropdown from LaunchedEffect

Comment: you need to have different success values as key in your launched effect. Whichever value in your view model is associated with your launched effect, that launched effect will be triggered when there is a change in that specific value. You need to have different functions for updating different values inside view model for different options.